# Improving performance of word extraction

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, data-structures, nlp

I have written the following code:

```py
temp_list = processed_text.split()
print(temp_list)

emotion_lists = {
    'admiration': [], 'amusement': [], 'anger': [], 'annoyance': [],
    'approval': [], 'caring': [], 'confusion': [], 'curiosity': [],
    'desire': [], 'disappointment': [], 'disapproval': [], 'disgust': [],
    'embarrassment': [], 'excitement': [], 'fear': [], 'gratitude': [],
    'grief': [], 'joy': [], 'love': [], 'nervousness': [], 'optimism': [],
    'pride': [], 'realization': [], 'relief': [], 'remorse': [], 'sadness': [],
    'surprise': []
}

for x in temp_list:
    results = emotion_pipeline(x) # Emotion Prediction Pipeline using EmoRoBERTa
    if results != 'neutral':
        for result in results:
            top_label = max(result, key=lambda dictionary: dictionary['score'])
            label = top_label["label"]
            if label in emotion_lists:
                emotion_lists[label].append(x)
            
print(emotion_lists)
```

But it takes a long time to execute long paragraphs. How can one further optimize it?

I've removed unnecessary code lines and included an if else statement to completely ignore the appending or 'neutral' words and removed the neutral list from `emotion_list`. This reduced the time from 1 min 45 secs to 1 min 22 secs.

Here's the text for the benchmark:

```
Today, I want to take a moment to reflect on the beauty of life and share some thoughts that have been resonating with me lately.

Life is an intricate tapestry of experiences, emotions, and connections. It is a journey filled with ups and downs, twists and turns, and unexpected surprises. It's easy to get caught up in the daily grind and lose sight of the wonder that surrounds us. However, it is in these moments of reflection that we can truly appreciate the magnificence of life.

Think about the simple pleasures that bring you joy: a warm cup of coffee on a chilly morning, the gentle touch of a loved one, or the breathtaking colors of a sunset. These seemingly ordinary moments are what make life extraordinary. By cultivating an attitude of gratitude, we can find beauty and fulfillment in even the smallest things.

Life is also about growth and learning. Each experience, whether pleasant or challenging, offers an opportunity for personal development. It is through adversity that we discover our strength and resilience. Embracing change and stepping out of our comfort zones can lead to profound transformations and new horizons. Remember, it's not about the destination but the journey itself.

Moreover, life is about connections and relationships. Our interactions with others shape our experiences and contribute to our sense of belonging. Take a moment to cherish the people who have touched your life, be it family, friends, or even strangers who have shown kindness. Nurture these relationships, for they provide support, understanding, and shared moments of laughter and tears.

While life can be unpredictable and challenging, it is essential to maintain a sense of hope and optimism. Embrace the power of dreams and aspirations, for they fuel our passions and drive us forward. Celebrate your achievements, no matter how small, and use setbacks as stepping stones to greater success.

In conclusion, life is a precious gift, and it is up to us to make the most of it. Let us approach each day with gratitude, curiosity, and an open heart. Embrace the beauty that surrounds you, seek personal growth, nurture relationships, and hold onto hope. Remember, the true essence of life lies not in its length but in the depth of our experiences
```

Time of execution of `emotion_pipeline`:

[image: Time of execution of emotion_pipeline]

Output of `emotion_pipeline` (for the last word) of the `temp_list`:

```
[[{'label': 'admiration', 'score': 0.0011110481573268771}, {'label': 'amusement', 'score': 0.0023590335622429848}, {'label': 'anger', 'score': 8.838719077175483e-05}, {'label': 'annoyance', 'score': 0.00025082440697588027}, {'label': 'approval', 'score': 0.0007353303371928632}, {'label': 'caring', 'score': 4.328513750806451e-05}, {'label': 'confusion', 'score': 5.098163819639012e-05}, {'label': 'curiosity', 'score': 3.086668220930733e-05}, {'label': 'desire', 'score': 4.53599714091979e-05}, {'label': 'disappointment', 'score': 7.120604277588427e-05}, {'label': 'disapproval', 'score': 0.00014575349632650614}, {'label': 'disgust', 'score': 0.00015191144484560937}, {'label': 'embarrassment', 'score': 2.4345894416910596e-05}, {'label': 'excitement', 'score': 5.621055970550515e-05}, {'label': 'fear', 'score': 3.3071850339183584e-05}, {'label': 'gratitude', 'score': 1.76055655174423e-05}, {'label': 'grief', 'score': 1.189570775750326e-05}, {'label': 'joy', 'score': 8.78259088494815e-05}, {'label': 'love', 'score': 4.430738772498444e-05}, {'label': 'nervousness', 'score': 1.218793750012992e-05}, {'label': 'optimism', 'score': 5.256943040876649e-05}, {'label': 'pride', 'score': 2.5214694687747397e-05}, {'label': 'realization', 'score': 9.513740224065259e-05}, {'label': 'relief', 'score': 6.58453109281254e-06}, {'label': 'remorse', 'score': 4.798649752046913e-05}, {'label': 'sadness', 'score': 0.00011766400712076575}, {'label': 'surprise', 'score': 2.1648049369105138e-05}, {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 0.9942617416381836}]]
```

Comment: You need to figure out where the time is being consumed. Try timing emotion_pipeline(x) to see how long that's taking before you do anything else. Looks like emotion_pipeline() can return multiple object types. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: I'm using JupyterNB extension on VSCode and it took me `1 min 19 secs` to complete the execution. `emotion_pipeline` returns the predicted score of the word and assigns a label to the predicted word. (as shown in the `emotion_lists`). It's implemented at the start of the code so that the model gets loaded before rather than loading it over and over again.

Comment: The python profiler(s) will, in general, help you figure out where time is used: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html  I have no idea how you would use that from Jupyter though...

Comment: How long does emotion_pipeline(x) take to run? What does it return?

Comment: In VSCode, its showing the amount of time taken for execution at the bottom-left corner.

Comment: I haven't looked, but I would have expected `emotion_pipeline` to take the text (and not individual words..)?

Comment: @DarkKnight `emotion_pipeline` alone takes `1 min 21.3secs'. See the updated query for more insight as I have posted screenshots too now.

Comment: @thebjorn Yes, you are right. I am now splitting the sentence so that it gets separately appended to different list for later use.

Comment: I think your `.split()` is splitting on words, not lines/sentences...

Comment: @DarkKnight here's the output of `emotion_pipeline`.
Output: `[[{'label': 'admiration', 'score': 0.0011110481573268771}, {'label': 'amusement', 'score': 0.0023590335622429848}, {'label': 'anger', 'score': 8.838719077175483e-05}, {'label': 'annoyance', 'score': 0.00025082440697588027}, {'label': 'approval', 'score': 0.0007353303371928632}, {'label': 'caring', 'score': 4.328513750806451e-05}, {'label': 'confusion', 'score': 5.098163819639012e-05}, {'label': 'curiosity', 'score': 3.086668220930733e-05}, {'label': 'desire', 'score': 4.53599714091979e-05}]`. (And more)

Comment: OK - So it's now clear that you'll have to improve the performance of emotion_pipeline() and we can't see the code for that. If it's something you've imported then you probably won't have any control over how it's implemented. Also, if the output is as shown in your comment (should be in the question), what are you hoping to achieve with *if results != 'neutral'* ?

Comment: @thebjorn Yeah sorry, it's splitting into words.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yep, you are right. But the code isn't publicly available. Its just downloads straight away as a pretrained model.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do other than contact the author(s) and suggest that they improve their code

Comment: (just to expand on DarkKnights comment.. You should put extra information in the question itself (i.e. edit the question) rather than in the comments, since comments can get unwieldy after a while). Is there perhaps another, lighter/smaller, model you can use?

Comment: Does it depend from system to system. As, this will be added to an API for highlighting the words which corresponds to each emotion. API is made on flask.

Comment: @thebjorn Can't we make a separate thread again for continuation. I myself am also feeling this is getting cumbersome for others. Also, there are other models but with limited parameters (Mostly with 6 labels), EmoRoBERTa has over 21 parameters.

Comment: Each request in flask is potentially a new process so a separate thread probably won't help you. A daemon process might though, perhaps running a http.server.HTTPServer (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)..?

Comment: Hi,
Apologies for the late response. I've read the documentation and what I've understood is that it would get too complex to implement it using a daemon process. Already two separate models are being utilized in my project.